# How to define max queue size using Spring-JMS

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I followed Spring-boot article to define local activemq:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/

I would like to set the queue size(for X times). so when producer try to enqueue new times it will get expcetion in case the size is on it's limit

How could I define that?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't limit the queues of ActiveMQ is number of messages in an easy way. There is an [open ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5522) you can vote for.

You can, however, limit the queue in memory size (bytes), but that was not the question.

Comment: Gotha.. thats a bit of a prob. I need to limit my queue by num of items inside

Comment: So do I, that's why started the discussion leading to that ticket. If I have a slot, I will start look at it, but currently I don't have that possibility.